# Horizontal and Dashed lines in caption

Tags: captions, rules

What I'm looking to do is caption a graph with something like

"It can be seen from x (solid line) and y (dashed line)"

Where "solid line" and "dashed line" are replaced by two solid and dashed lines centered vertically inline with the text of the caption.

Using

```
\protect\rule{1cm}{.4pt}
```

Gives a solid line, but it is not centered with respect to the height of the text.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `rule` command has a "raise" optional argument:

```
\rule[0.5ex]{1cm}{0.4pt}
```

You can define

```
\newcommand\solidrule[1][1cm]{\rule[0.5ex]{#1}{.4pt}}
\newcommand\dashedrule{\mbox{%
  \solidrule[2mm]\hspace{2mm}\solidrule[2mm]\hspace{2mm}\solidrule[2mm]}}
```

and then use

```
It can be seen from x (\solidrule) and y (\protect\dashedrule)
```

Comment: Can you please give an example how to extend the `\dashedrule` to 14 cm? Can the rule has a parameter where you decide its length?

Comment: @Masi That's a completely new question

Answer (score 4):

shift the rule with the optional argument:

```
\rule[0.6ex]{1cm}{.4pt}
```